# First condition can't run (can't print the date according to the input date form)

Tags: javascript, php, html

The code can't run the first condition `if` (can't print the date according to the input date form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); //Set your timezone
    $date = new DateTime;
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <!-- today date-->
    <input type="date" name="today" value="<?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="test">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['today'])){
    $datePOST = new DateTime($_POST['today']);
    echo $datePOST->format('d/m/Y');}ELSE{echo 'ss';}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested your code and everything is working fine. Can you describe more clearly the output you get?